# Spring Form:Form not finding controller method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to submit a form, however the form:form is not finding controller method. I can't see, to find out why it is not finding it. I have tried many different things, but yet it still isn't finding it. Can anyone help me. Here is my JSP

```
<form:form action="/Dashboard/create/team" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Team Name: </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Example FC">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Logo: </label>
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Stadium Name: </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Stadium name...">
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Stadium Picture: </label>
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
</div>
<input type="submit">
</form:form>
```

These are the JSTL inputs I have

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

And here is my controller method:

```
@PostMapping( value= "/Dashboard/create/team")
public String create_this_team(Model model, @RequestParam("logo") MultipartFile logo, @RequestParam("stad") MultipartFile stad, WebRequest req) throws SerialException, SQLException, IOException {
     //CODE
    return "HTML/Admin/teams";
}
```

If anyone can find out why this isn't working can you please let me know. I've never had any problems with any of the other form:form's that I have used.
Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by _it's not finding it_?

Comment: I am getting a 404 error, when executing the form, the return is correct is copy and pasted from the method which returns the page in the first place, if I put a print method at the top of the method, it is not printed

Comment: What do the spring logs print?

Comment: Nothing, there is nothing on the console or on the error page.

Comment: Turn on your logs and see what they print. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think its something to do with the @RequestParam, yeah when I remove it the form submits. I'll have a look if I can fix it.